# Angular Js orderBy with numeric field is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In controller I have written code that convert rank into Float

```
details.rank = '';
$scope.order = function (predicate) {
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    if (predicate == 'rank') {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.countries[$scope.index].cities.length; i++) {
            details.rank = parseFloat(data.countries[$scope.index].cities[i].rank);
        }
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
    } else $scope.predicate = predicate;
};
```

but here I am getting error that **ReferenceError: details is not defined**

I have json like this:

```
{
    "countries": [{
        "country": "India",
        "cities": [{
            "name": "Bangalore",
            "rank": "40"
        }, {
            "name": "Kolkata",
            "rank": "54"
        }, {
            "name": "Mumbai",
            "rank": "32"
        }, {
            "name": "Chennai",
            "rank": "42"
        }]
    }, {
        "country": "China",
        "cities": [{
            "name": "Guangzhou",
            "rank": "111"
        }, {
            "name": "Beijing",
            "rank": "90"
        }, {
            "name": "Fuzhou",
            "rank": "21"
        }, {
            "name": "Baotou",
            "rank": "23"
        }]
    }]
}
```

In **html** if I click header of table then it will sort the table both ascending and descending order but I am unable to do this.

```
<th>
    <a href="" ng-click="order('rank')">RANK</a>
    <span ng-show="predicate === 'rank'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}">     </span>
</th>
<ul ng-repeat="city in countryType">
    <li ng-repeat="details in city.data.cities | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <div class="text" id="t1"> {{details.name}} </div>
        <div class="text" id="t2"> {{details.rank}}</div>
        <div class="text" id="t3"> {{details.population}} </div>
        <div class="text" id="t4"> {{details.language}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: all are working fine, I want only convert my rank field in json file to float or int value so that I will be able to sort.

Comment: the `details` just exits in ng-repeat scope, so there is no `details` any more in controller

Comment: okay if use $scope.details.name then it also gives me error like **TypeError: Cannot set property 'rank' of undefined**

Comment: $scope.details off course undefined, it's just a variable in ng-repeat directive scope, so in controller I think you should edit your original data, maybe `$scope.city.data.cities`

Comment: if `details` is not defiend make sure you define it before using it. I think you use `'use strict'`. Make : `var details = {};` at the top of your file

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dynamic sorting by clicking on the header divs doing like that :

```
<ul ng-repeat="city in countryType">
    <li>
        <div class="text" ng-click="orderListBy('name')"> Name </div>
        <div class="text" ng-click="orderListBy('rank')"> Rank</div>
        <div class="text" ng-click="orderListBy('population')"> Population </div>
        <div class="text" ng-click="orderListBy('language')"> Language</div>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="details in city.data.cities | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <div class="text" id="t1-{{$index}}"> {{details.name}} </div>
        <div class="text" id="t2-{{$index}}"> {{details.rank}}</div>
        <div class="text" id="t3-{{$index}}"> {{details.population}} </div>
        <div class="text" id="t4-{{$index}}"> {{details.language}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in your controller

```
//initialize values
$scope.predicate = 'rank';
$scope.reverse = false;

$scope.orderListBy = function(attr){
    $scope.predicate = attr;
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};
```

Doing so it will revert the sort when re-clicking on the header of a column.

PS : don't forget to dynamically name your IDs in the ng-repeat directive to avoid errors and have a valid HTML code.